# Can not login into server due to NFS mount failed

Tags: linux, nfs, fstab

I have two servers:

Server A: NFS Server

Server B: It mounts a directory via NFS from Instance A

The problem is that Server A IP is configured in the Server B fstab to mount the directory while booting. When the Server A is stopped for some reason, its IP changes and the Server B gets blocked while booting. I can't access Server B to change the IP of Server A.

Any idea about how to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Well, don't let server A change addresses then, use a static one.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the mount to a soft mount by using the `soft` option in `/etc/fstab`, or the `mount` command.  Soft mounts, unlike the default, will timeout after a while.  You can control the length of timeout with the `timeo=X` mount option, where X is measured in seconds.

Comment: Additionally, if it's possible, you can use `autofs` to mount the filesystem rather than hard-coding it into `fstab`. This way, the filesystem comes online when it's needed, not necessarily when the system is trying to boot. (And if it's not available right way, it'll come up when it is.)